# MySql Specific Search - Replace String

Tags: mysql

I need to search words that contain multiple number prefixes.
Example:
0119
0129
0139
0149

But there is other prefixes, 0155859, 0128889
Etc.

If i search 0%9 it'll come up with all the results i don't want, it'll include the 0155859, 0128889 ones

I need to search and list ONLY the ones that have 0119, etc
How do i do it ?

0XX9 ( Where XX is any strings that matches, so 0119, 0129, etc. % Lists all other characters till a 9 appears, i don't want that. )

I'm trying on my english, correct me if i did'nt expressed myself right !

Comment: The best way to express yourself here is by giving sample data and desired result.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My gut feeling at seeing your question was to consider using `REGEXP`, which is MySQL's regex matching operator.  Try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE word REGEXP '0[0-9][0-9]9'
```

The pattern used would match any word containing a zero, followed by any two numbers, followed by a 9.

Comment: Thx, that did it

Answer (score -1):

In a `LIKE` pattern, the `_` character matches any single character. So you can do:

```
WHERE word LIKE '0__9%'
```

This matches a word that begins with `0`, then any two characters, then `9`, then anything after that.